# I can't fetch array elements on view section that have been passed from the controller using foreach() method

Tags: codeigniter

I passed the array that have been fetched from the model into the view section. The values are fetched on controller part as well as on the view part. The used the foreach() method to fetch the array elements as shown below

Controller Part

```
function view_savings()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata(uname);
        $report['savings'] = $this->money_m->get_savings($user);
        $this->load->view('showsavings',$report);
    }
```

View Part

```
<?php 
      foreach($savings as $vs)
      {
          echo $vs->username; 
          echo $vs->stype;  
          echo $vs->inst_name;  
          echo $vs->acc_name;  
          echo $vs->smonth;  
          echo $vs->syear; 
       }
?>
```

The array values are displayed from the $savings array(). Is there any problem with my code. Please help me..

Comment: please post get_saving model function

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the view,

```
print_r($report['savings']);
```

With above code are you getting any result??

Comment: I have done the same. It shows values both in the controller part and view part.. But the values are not displayed on the view part.. In the above code $savings returns an empty array..

Comment: ok, inside foreach print_r($vs) n check if you are getting any value.

Comment: if ur print_r($data['savings']) in controller, its working, but if u do print_r($savings) in view, its not working??

Comment: @Jasir,please print your data as directed by Niranjan.

Answer (score 0):

just try it

```
<?php 

  if(isset($savings) && count($savings) > 0)
  {
   foreach($savings as $vs)
   {
      echo $vs['username']; 
      echo $vs['stype'];  
      echo $vs['inst_name'];  
      echo $vs['acc_name'];  
      echo $vs['smonth'];  
      echo $vs['syear']; 
    }
   }
?>
```

Good Luck ['}

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your view

```
  <?php 
  foreach($savings->result() as $vs)
  {
      echo $vs->username; 
      echo $vs->stype;  
      echo $vs->inst_name;  
      echo $vs->acc_name;  
      echo $vs->smonth;  
      echo $vs->syear; 
   }
   ?>
```